# Typo3 Extensions accessing multiple database tables

Tags: database, typo3

I have an extension built with extension builder. It also has a front end plugin. This has its own dedicated table `tx_planner_domain_model_planner`. Now this extension needs to access other database table `pages` to do some processing.

Is this possible in Typo3?

My initial idea, was to create a php code that connects to the database. But i'm assuming I can create model objects and use them.

Comment: First Question: what is the extension key? are you sure that the table name is "pages"? If you created the extension with kickstarter, the table might be called "tx_planner_pages" instead of "pages". - Second Question: Do you want to connect to a table "Pages" in an _external_ database? That would be much more cpmplicated, and in  order to get a useful answer you should clarify this your question.

Answer (score 0):

Extension Builder supports 'mapping' to existing tables, just add there for an example `Page` mark as a agregate root and in `Map to existing table` field write... `pages`. Ignore warning about the type field and **save anyway**

later in your `typo3conf/ext/planner/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt` add this mapping rule:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {
    Tx_Planner_Domain_Model_Page {
        mapping {
            tableName = pages
        }
    }
}
```

After that add proper fields and getters/setters in `Tx_Planner_Domain_Model_Page` model, inject the `Tx_Planner_Domain_Model_PageRepository` into desired controller and ...

**MOST IMPORTANT:** clear the whole cache or you'll get a lot of mysterious errors!

Comment: This is the error i'm getting : 
`1247602160: Unknown column 'pages.sys_language_uid' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pages WHERE pages.deleted=0 AND (pages.sys_language_uid IN (0,-1))`

This is what i did : In my `Planner.php` from `Domain/Model/` folder I added a field and getters/setters for `title` in `pages` table. 

in my 'PlannerController' I injected the repository.

Comment: from `Data/`? He means the TYPO3 cache (header bar in backend).